# Accessing multiple matched objects in a function without explicitly stating the names in the function call

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, environment, scoping

I would like to develop a simple function that would enable me to save graphs of specific characteristics. For example, I'm running some analysis producing a set of histograms:

```
# Data  and Libs
data(mtcars); require(ggplot2)

# Graphs

## A
grph_a <- ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_histogram(aes(mpg)) +
  ggtitle("MPG")

## B
grph_b <- ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_histogram(aes(cyl)) +
  ggtitle("CYL")
```

Instead of writing `ggsave` command for each of those graphs I would like to do it via function. It makes sense as I will be repeating the same steps for a number of graphs across various similar projects. I would like for the function to do one thing:

- *For all the graphs that have a specific string in name run `ggsave` with a set parameters and save them to provide path.*

Ideally, I would like for the function call to look like that

```
ExportGraphs(graphNamePhrase = "grph_", filesPath = "Somewhere/GaphsAndStuff/)
```

I don't want to be specifying more stuff.

## Function

My function looks like that:

```
ExportGraphs <- function(graphNamePhrase = "grph_",
                         filesPath, objects = ls()) {

  # Check if required packages are available
  req_pkgs <- c("ggplot2","grid")
  ## Check if the package is loaded and load if needed
  for (i in 1:length(req_pkgs)) {
    pkg <- req_pkgs[i]
    if (length(grep(pkg, search())) == 0) {
      lapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)
    }
  }

  # Create list of objects
  save_grphs <- grep(pattern = graphNamePhrase, x = objects,
                     ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)

  # Create save loop
  for (i in 1:length(save_grphs)) {

    # Create file path
    fle_path <- paste0(filesPath, save_grphs[i], ".png")

    # Save file
    ggsave(filename = fle_path, plot = save_grphs[i],
           width = 7, height = 7, units = 'cm', scale = 2, dpi = 600)
  }

}
```

### Problems

Obviously, the code:

```
  save_grphs <- grep(pattern = graphNamePhrase, x = objects,
                     ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)
```

won't work as what is passed via the `objects = ls()` will be a string. My question is how can I get around it. Is there a way to use `get` on the parent frame from which the function is called? Not the easiest solution but I could search objects via string. Or can I run `ls` with `grep` in the function call and pass all matching objects?

---

## Comments Follow-up

### mget

I tried the solution with `mget`:

```
ExportGraphs <- function(graphNamePhrase = "grph_",
                         filesPath, objects = ls()) {

  # Check if required packages are available
  req_pkgs <- c("ggplot2","grid")
  ## Check if the package is loaded and load if needed
  for (i in 1:length(req_pkgs)) {
    pkg <- req_pkgs[i]
    if (length(grep(pkg, search())) == 0) {
      lapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)
    }
  }

  # Create list of objects
  save_grphs <- grep(pattern = graphNamePhrase, x = objects,
                     ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)
  save_grphs <- mget(objects[save_grphs])

  # Create save loop
  for (i in 1:length(save_grphs)) {

    # Create file path
    fle_path <- paste0(filesPath, save_grphs[i], ".png")

    # Save file
    ggsave(filename = fle_path, plot = save_grphs[[i]],
           width = 7, height = 7, units = 'cm', scale = 2, dpi = 600)
  }

}
```

But it seems that I would have to adjust the loop as subscription appears to be out of bounds:

> ```
> Error in save_grphs[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
> Called from: inherits(plot, "ggplot")
> ```

Comment: Try `save_grphs <- mget(objects[save_grphs])`. And when you call it below use double brackets as it will be in a list `plot = save_grphs[[i]]...`

Comment: Thank you very much, I will be happy to try. It didn't cross my mind to use the `mget` but it looks like a promising solution.

Comment: Put the plots in a list to begin with and you won't need `mget`.

Comment: `Vectorize(require)(package = c("ggplot2","grid"), char = TRUE)` or something instead of that loop. `require` checks if packages are loaded anyway

Comment: @Roland could do but I would like to use the function on some scripts that were developed in past. Ideally, generic function will make my life easier as in practice it boils down to a slightly elaborate wrapper around `ggsave`. I may also add some other export mechanism if required (slides or whatever). The key is to have: objects and object name to pass to path and file name.

Comment: @rawr Why not, ideally I want to avoid loading packages twice. I may expend the function to handle `ggmap` objects. I don't want to be loading 4/5 packages each time.

Comment: Using systematic names like `grph_a`, `grph_b` is a sign of bad practice. Good practice is putting them in a list and passing all objects needed inside a function as arguments (and not fetching them from environments outside the function). It shouldn't be too hard to improve the legacy code to `grph$a <-` instead of `grph_a <-`.

Comment: like I said, require (and library) check that packages are loaded and do not reload them if they are

Comment: @Roland with respect to general practice point taken. This time I just want to get the function to work. Also from an educational point of view I'm interested in learning more about making use of environments in R.

Comment: I just noticed that you used `value=TRUE` in your grep call for `save_graphs`. Take that out.

Comment: @PierreLafortune I tried `grep(pattern = graphNamePhrase, x = objects,
                     ignore.case = TRUE)` but got the same error.

Comment: The `save_graphs` index was saved over. So the filepath won't work. Have to go to now but will return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me. There are many places to further optimize the function:

```
ExportGraphs <- function(graphNamePhrase = "grph_",
                         filesPath, objects = ls()) {

  # Check if required packages are available
  req_pkgs <- c("ggplot2","grid")
  ## Check if the package is loaded and load if needed
  for (i in 1:length(req_pkgs)) {
    pkg <- req_pkgs[i]
    if (length(grep(pkg, search())) == 0) {
      lapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)
    }
  }

  # Create list of objects
  index <- grep(pattern = graphNamePhrase, x = objects,
                     ignore.case = TRUE)
  save_grphs <- mget(objects[index])
  # Create save loop
  for (i in 1:length(save_grphs)) {

    # Create file path
    fle_path <- paste0(filesPath, objects[index][i], ".png")

    # Save file
    ggsave(filename = fle_path, plot = save_grphs[[i]],
           width = 7, height = 7, units = 'cm', scale = 2, dpi = 600)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
ExportGraphs <- function(graphNamePhrase = "grph_", 
                         filesPath = "Somewhere/GaphsAndStuff",
                         object = ls()) {
  lapply(object[substr(names(object), 1, nchar(graphNamePhrase)) == graphNamePhrase], 
         function(plot.list.el){
           ggsave(plot.list.el, filename = paste(filesPath, paste0(names(plot.list.el), 
                                                                   ".pdf"),
                                                 sep = "/"))
         })
}


# testing the function
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100))
object <- list(grph_asd = ggplot(dat, aes(x = x)) + geom_histogram(),
               grp_noplot = ggplot(dat, aes(x)) + geom_histogram())

# save the first, but not the second plot to the working directory

ExportGraphs(filesPath = "~", object = object)
```